# R demos for presentation

Tags: r, presentation, demo

I know this is barely programming related, but I'll have to show some intuitive, straightforward and possibly very appealing R presentation so that a department at my current institution will start to evaluate its adoption.
Does anyone of you know any R script that shows the power, simplicity and flexibility of R?
I'm looking especially for scripts belonging to two categories:

- easy code showing how quick it is to calculate descriptives, basic plots like barchart, boxplots, simple linear regression - all of that concisely and beautifully
- code showing fancy visualizations of complex multivariate datasets (ie. heatmaps etc)

Interactivity for scripts belonging to the second category is a plus.

Of course having data to use with the scripts would also be appreciated ;)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Quick-R is a nice site for some examples on how you can easilly do a ton of useful stuff in R:

http://www.statmethods.net/

---

For fancy visualizations, check out some of the examples from my package `qgraph`:)

http://sites.google.com/site/qgraphproject/examples

Most of those pictures are included in the help files ( `?qgraph.pca`, `?qgraph.efa` )

And of course check out examples from `ggplot2`

Answer (score 12):

The `demo()` command is your friend. Use the ones for lattice and ggplot2 and you'll soon convert people to R through the extremely high quality graphics.

Answer (score 7):

I've done similar things, and here are some things that I included as good examples;

- Grabbing data from a Wikipedia page, process and display a graph of the explosion in colours of Crayola crayons since they were introduced, all in thirty lines of code (http://www.r-bloggers.com/ggplot2-crayola-crayon-colours/)
- Showing the exponential rise of R packages on CRAN over time (http://journal.r-project.org/archive/2009-2/RJournal_2009-2_Fox.pdf)
- How the New York Times used R to create an amazing infographic showing the hits of Michael Jackson in the three hours after his death (http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2009/06/25/arts/0625-jackson-graphic.html)
- Pretty much any of the examples for ggplot2, because of my area of expertise, I often do [these](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/geom_boxplot.html) (http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/)

I shoe-horned most of these, and a few work-specific ones into a Sweave file that used the [Beamer](http://www.shawnlankton.com/tag/beamer/) Poster [styles](http://www-i6.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/~dreuw/latexbeamerposter.php) to produce a scientific poster that compiles itself, and can pull current datasets every time, which always seems to impress.

Answer (score 6):

And let's not forget the [`googleVis` package](http://code.google.com/p/google-motion-charts-with-r/) (an R interface to the Google Visualization API), to produce cool motion-charts (as seen in the "Joy of Stats" videos by [Hans Rosling](http://www.gapminder.org/)) with just a couple lines of code. Although perhaps not directly relevant to what the original question asked for, showing that R now has a spiffy IDE called [RStudio](http://www.rstudio.org/) can also help convince people to adopt R, especially those who think that Matlab has a nice editor and R doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

The [AniWiki](http://animation.yihui.name/) web site containing a gallery of statistical animations produced using the [animation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/animation/index.html) package by Yihui Xie could be of some use to you.

Answer (score 1):

Faraway's book has tons of great code you can copy and paste in, appendix C seems to be what you need to start out

http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Faraway-PRA.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar discussion [How to market R at your institute?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/52192/how-to-market-r-at-your-institute) first here at SO which was moved later on to programmers. Maybe it's not as concrete as this one, but still you might find some synergies.