# Erlang demo app?

Tags: erlang

I'm in a group at work reading [Seven Languages in Seven Weeks by Bruce A. Tate](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/193435659X) and we are having a presentation on one language each week.  I'm partially responsible for Erlang in 2 weeks and am looking for a good demo app that would show off the strengths of Erlang.  I plan to go through the programming exercises in the book, but am looking for that little, interesting app for the demo.  I will need to be able to write it in just a few hours once I become more familiar with the language.  Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: wondering why the close votes on this.  Other calls for demo apps such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311342/r-demos-for-presentation and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098544/looking-for-a-demo-project-to-present-maven have no close votes, and the R one is actually quite popular.

Comment: here's what I ended up doing http://digitaljoel.nerd-herders.com/2011/03/31/erlang-concurrency-demo-application/

Comment: You might want to consider adding a link to the demo you chose as an answer to your own question and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up [writing an answer](http://digitaljoel.nerd-herders.com/2011/03/31/project-euler-problem-22-in-erlang/) to [Project Euler's problem 22](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=22) in order to show some of the list functions, then I came up with a [concurrency app](http://digitaljoel.nerd-herders.com/2011/03/31/erlang-concurrency-demo-application/) on my own which was pretty well received.  Thanks Adam and Mazen for the thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

I ran a neat demo at Dyncon in Stockholm last weekend: https://gist.github.com/854389

It's a "virus" that jumps between connected nodes (which the attendees start on their machines and connect to the presenter's already "infected" node).

It demos distribution very nicely. To complement, I started up an Erlang shell and spawned over a million idle processes (that waited in a receive loop), printing every thousand process number to the shell, until my laptop ran out of memory. Very nice effect. :-)

Comment: That looks cool.  We will only have one machine we are demonstrating on, so it might be difficult to do the virus one, but it gets the wheels turning.

Comment: It is also possible to bring up, for example, four Erlang shells on the screen (tell the audience that it is four "servers") and then connect them one by one. It's a nice effect.

Answer (score 1):

If you want you can take a look at eirc. It is more of an IRC library but it is a compliant OTP app. Easy to understand and to use and build on (example in the README file) so I think it would be good for a first project.

You can find it here: https://github.com/mazenharake/eirc